# Is there a durable surface that ants can't pass?

Tags: ant

I'm looking for a surface, that will be impassable for ant's yet not poisonous or easily decaying.

One idea is water - they really can't cross that. But water easily dries and is quite uncomfortable.

Is there something their legs will find uncomfortable? Something spiky for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fluon is a substance that people use to make artificial ant nests. It is similar to teflon in property and fluon coated surfaces are too slippery for ants to cross. See [here](http://krungkuene.org/ameisen_page/fluon.html).

Answer (score 6):

I've found that ants do not walk through petroleum jelly. It is also convenient, as it isn't too messy, and can be whatever shape you want. I use it to keep ants from climbing into my hummingbird feeders. Make sure the area you treat is wider than the ant is long.

Answer (score 0):

Vinegar is something that the ants will not walk through,due to the fact that the vinegar overwhelms their senses.